# Android Calender Edit Event Unknown URI Content in Android 2.3

Tags: android, android-calendar

In my calender app I am not able to edit my calender's events for Android 2.x, but it works well for 4 versions.

This is my content uri which works when I add events for versions 2.x but gives exception when I do edit my events.

```
eventUriString = "content://com.android.calendar/events";
```

Here is my method:

```
public static long editAppointmentsToCalender(Context curActivity,int calenderId, String title,
        String addInfo, String place, int status, long startDateTime, long endDateTime, boolean needReminder,
        boolean needMailService, int repeat,String[] selArgs,String[] selArgs2) {

    String eventUriString = null;
    ContentValues eventValues = new ContentValues();
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 8 && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= 14){
        eventUriString = "content://com.android.calendar/events";

        eventValues.put("calendar_id", calenderId);
        eventValues.put("title", title);
        eventValues.put("description", addInfo);
        eventValues.put("eventLocation", place);
        eventValues.put("dtstart", startDateTime);
        eventValues.put("dtend", endDateTime);
        eventValues.put("rrule","FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=2");
        eventValues.put("eventStatus", status); 
        eventValues.put("visibility", 3);
        eventValues.put("transparency", 0); 
        eventValues.put("hasAlarm", 1); 
        eventValues.put("eventTimezone", Time.getCurrentTimezone());
        eventID = curActivity.getContentResolver().update(Uri.parse(eventUriString), eventValues,"event_id =? ", selArgs);
        System.out.println("is updated===>"+eventID);
    }else if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 15){          
        eventUriString = CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI.toString();

        eventValues.put(CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID, calenderId);
        eventValues.put(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, title);
        eventValues.put(CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION, addInfo);
        eventValues.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_LOCATION, place);
        eventValues.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART, startDateTime);
        eventValues.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTEND, endDateTime);
        eventValues.put(CalendarContract.Events.RRULE, "FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=1");
        eventValues.put(CalendarContract.Events.STATUS, status);
        eventValues.put(CalendarContract.Events.HAS_ALARM, 1);


        TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getDefault();
        eventValues.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, timeZone.getID());
        eventID = curActivity.getContentResolver().update(Uri.parse(eventUriString), eventValues,Events._ID + " =? ", selArgs);
        System.out.println("is updated===>"+eventID);
    }else{
        eventUriString = "content://calendar/calendars";
        eventValues.put("calendar_id", calenderId);
        eventValues.put("title", title);
        eventValues.put("description", addInfo);
        eventValues.put("eventLocation", place);
        eventValues.put("dtstart", startDateTime);
        eventValues.put("dtend", endDateTime);
        eventValues.put("eventStatus", status); 
        eventValues.put("visibility", 3);
        eventValues.put("transparency", 0); 
        eventValues.put("hasAlarm", 1); 
         eventID = curActivity.getContentResolver().update(Uri.parse(eventUriString), eventValues,"event_id =? ", selArgs);
         System.out.println("is updated===>"+eventID);
    }
```

Error Log:

```
11-30 19:52:11.117: E/AndroidRuntime(20457): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-30 19:52:11.117: E/AndroidRuntime(20457): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown      URL content://com.android.calendar/events
11-30 19:52:11.117: E/AndroidRuntime(20457):    at   android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:144)
11-30 19:52:11.117: E/AndroidRuntime(20457):    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:114)
11-30 19:52:11.117: E/AndroidRuntime(20457):    at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.update(ContentProviderNative.java:510)
11-30 19:52:11.117: E/AndroidRuntime(20457):    at android.content.ContentResolver.update(ContentResolver.java:724)
11-30 19:52:11.117: E/AndroidRuntime(20457):    at com.example.calendar.CreateEvent.editAppointmentsToCalender(CreateEvent.java:129)
11-30 19:52:11.117: E/AndroidRuntime(20457):    at com.example.calendar.CreateEventActivity$3.onClick(CreateEventActivity.java:110)
11-30 19:52:11.117: E/AndroidRuntime(20457):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
11-30 19:52:11.117: E/AndroidRuntime(20457):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
11-30 19:52:11.117: E/AndroidRuntime(20457):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
11-30 19:52:11.117: E/AndroidRuntime(20457):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-30 19:52:11.117: E/AndroidRuntime(20457):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
11-30 19:52:11.117: E/AndroidRuntime(20457):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
11-30 19:52:11.117: E/AndroidRuntime(20457):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-30 19:52:11.117: E/AndroidRuntime(20457):    at  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-30 19:52:11.117: E/AndroidRuntime(20457):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
11-30 19:52:11.117: E/AndroidRuntime(20457):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
11-30 19:52:11.117: E/AndroidRuntime(20457):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: The Calendar `ContentProvider` was not documented and supported in Android 2.x. It definitely does not have the same `Uri` structure as in 4.x.

Comment: @CommonsWare Can you please suggest me a way to do the same in 2.x versions ?

Comment: @GauravArora: I wouldn't do it in 2.x versions, as it is undocumented and unsupported.

Comment: @CommonsWareThanks for sharing the knowledge, so what if we have to make our single consildated application for all the versions including lower one's, which support the same. Is there any other way out.

Comment: @AkhileshMani were you resolve this issue?